# The same css code doesn't give me the same result

Tags: javascript, css, mysql, node.js, reactjs

I'am making a login page and i have a problem with css not making the same format for the email and the password despite writing the same code in css
This is the code:

```css
.main {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  padding: 90px 0 90px 0;
  background-color: rgb(252, 252, 252);
}

.sub-main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 520px;
  width: 50%;
  box-shadow: 11px 12px 13px 12px rgb(252, 252, 252);
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(210, 180, 140, 0.644);
}

.imgs {
  padding-top: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.user {
  height: 90px;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 130px;
  color: rosybrown;
  font-size: 120px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

input {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 25px 0px #888;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.sub-main.data.email {
  height: 100px;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 14px 0 0 25px;
  color: rosybrown;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.username {
  height: 100px;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 14px 0 0 25px;
  color: rosybrown;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.sub-main.data.password {
  height: 100px;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 14px 0 0 25px;
  color: rosybrown;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.name {
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

.second-input {
  padding-top: 9px;
}

button {
  width: 380px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  background-color: tan;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: none;
}

.login-button {
  padding-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div className="main">

  <div className="sub-main">
    <div>
      <div className="imgs">
        <div className="user">
          <i className="bi bi-person-badge-fill"></i>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="data">
        <div>
          <input onChange={(e)=> setEmail(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="Adresse email" className="email" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input onChange={(e)=> setPassword(e.target.value)} type="password" placeholder="Mot de passe" className="password" />
        </div>

        <div>
          <div className="login-button">
            <button type="submit">Connexion</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I gave the same characteristics for both email and password but they have different formats,is it something to do with classname?
This is the result i get :
[image]

Comment: Your code snippet has an error in it. Please fix

Comment: The code provided does not reproduce the issue.  Please include a [mre] to your question

Comment: className won't do anything within an HTML (or JSX) element.  It should be 'class='

Comment: @James good catch! although in this case, it's not the issue (with the code provided anyway)

Comment: I took the code and removed the jsx style event listeners so it would render in the snippet tool.  The username and password fields look to be the same style, and not like the picture above.

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/p0wyo9xg/1/

Comment: @James you can see it in the snippet above too (run it)

Comment: @blurfus It breaks because of the JSX event listeners.

Comment: @James yes, my point being that you can see the buttons render the same and do not replicate the issue

Comment: @james i also don't get why it's not shown i tried other things and then redone the code the same as the one i put above i get a different result like the new scrreshot in my edited comment

Comment: did you change the `className=` in the HTML to `name=` as @James suggested ? - If not, you should start there

Answer (score 0):

you should change `.sub-main.data.email {` into `.sub-main .data .email {`.
also same change for password is needed.